# I have this error:" fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" in Xcode 8 swift 3

Tags: swift3, xcode8

this is my code

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  morpher app soundboard
//
//  Created by Jared Evan Miller on 7/24/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Jared Evan Miller. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {


let soundFilenames = ["5","8","7","4","6","Sound3forbutton3","sound2forbutton1","sound2forbutton2"]
var audioPlayers = [AVAudioPlayer]()
var lastAudioPlayer = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Set up audio players
    for sound in soundFilenames {

        do {

            // Try to do something

            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: sound, ofType: "wav")!)
            let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer (contentsOf:url)

            audioPlayers.append(audioPlayer)
        }
        catch {

            // Catch the error that is thrown
       audioPlayers.append(AVAudioPlayer())
        }
               }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // Get the audioPlayer that corresponds to the button that they tapped
    let lastPlayer = audioPlayers[lastAudioPlayer]
    lastPlayer.stop();
    lastAudioPlayer = sender.tag;
    lastPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    let audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
    audioPlayer.currentTime=0;
    audioPlayer.play()
}

    @IBAction func tbuttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // Get the audioPlayer that corresponds to the button that they tapped

    let lastPlayer = audioPlayers[lastAudioPlayer]
    lastPlayer.stop();
    lastAudioPlayer = sender.tag;
    lastPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    let audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
    audioPlayer.currentTime=0;
    audioPlayer.play()
}

}
```

How do I fix this?

Also, I get this error. this is the part in the code. look at what I changed. it has the error of when I run it on my iPhone se.

![my code][2]

[[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5WC3.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZnTV.png)
please help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are force unwrapping the result of Budle.main.path..., since this is failing it means  your resource is not loaded correctly.

Make sure your sound files are bundled with your app. You can check this by going to your project settings, then under "Build Phases" add the files to the "Copy Bundle Resources" section if they are not already there.

```
for sound in soundFilenames {

    guard let urlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: sound, ofType: "wav") else {

        print("Sound file not found: \(sound)")

        continue
    }

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath:urlString)

    do {

        // Try to do something
        let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer (contentsOf:url)

        audioPlayers.append(audioPlayer)
    }
    catch {

        // Catch the error that is thrown
        audioPlayers.append(AVAudioPlayer())
    }
}
```